# Android app - how to make my app available in the list of selectable navigation apps?

Tags: android

On my mobile browser I visit a route on the Komoot website. I can export this route (with coordinates) to a GPS device or app. I would like to see my navigation app in the list of GPS / navigation apps.

How to make my app available in the list of selectable navigation apps?

> Which mime-type in my intent-filter should I use in my App?

When using the default View or Send, the app is not shown in the list of GPS apps.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I looked at [this list](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mime-support/+/9817b71a54a2ee8b691c1dfa937c0f9b16b3473c/mime.types) and [another list](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java), but could not find a sensible solution.

Comment: You may want to install [Intent Intercept](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.k3b.android.intentintercept/) and just peek.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - can you promote your comment to an answer? I will up-vote and approve your answer.

Comment: Sure, added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's handy tool called **Intent Intercept** that will let you, as name indicates intercept many different intents. And once you got that, it will then let you peek it in details, that way you can see exactly what is being send and then adjust your code to match. The [original app](https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept) seems not to be maintained any more, yet as this is open source project, there's a [fork being actively developed](https://github.com/k3b/intent-intercept). You can get build directly from F-Droid: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.k3b.android.intentintercept/

[image]